# Desempenho de funções com e sem criação de variáveis locais

Tags: python, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Apesar da simplicidade desta pergunta, não consegui encontrar uma resposta para ela na Internet.

Existe alguma diferença estrutural/performática entre as duas funções definidas abaixo?

```
def F(x):

  Output = x + 1

  return Output
```

---

```
def F(x):

    return x + 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só para complementar a resposta do Maniero:

Você pode usar o módulo [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) (Disassembler) para checar a diferença entre os bytecodes gerados.

Ex.:

```
from dis import dis

def exemplo_1(x):
    output = x + 1
    return output

def exemplo_2(x):
    return x + 1

print('>>> dis(exemplo_1)')
dis(exemplo_1)

print('-' * 60)

print('>>> dis(exemplo_2)')
dis(exemplo_2)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-351830-6333) com o código rodando</sup>

A saída (no Python 3.7.1) é:

```
>>> dis(exemplo_1)
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (output)

  5           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (output)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------
>>> dis(exemplo_2)
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

É uma boa ferramenta para testar casos simples como este, por mais que você não entenda completamente a saída, você já consegue ver que o `exemplo_1` aloca memória para `ouput`.

Answer (score 6):

De forma geral posso dizer que é zero. O resultado deve ser o mesmo, isso não pode ser mudado. A performance também não é para ser diferente, mas nada garante. Esse tipo de coisa depende de implementação para determinar se alguma é mais rápida. Não existe só um Python. Todas as implementações devem apresentar o mesmo resultado, mas as características de performance de cada uma é problema dela.

Dito isso, eu sou contra a criação de variáveis sem necessidade. Variáveis devem existir por dois motivos:

- Precisa de um resultado intermediário ser guardado em algum lugar para uso posterior **em mais de um local**, portanto seria ruim ou produziria resultados errados se tiver que obter esse valor mais de uma vez; ou depende da ordem que a informação será adquirida e usada e por isso a guarda do valor é importante
- Precisa documentar melhor o que está fazendo aquilo que não é óbvio quando se lê, então uma variável com um **nome excelente** é usada para indicar o que é aquele resultado.

Em geral vejo programadores criando a variável porque eles não sabem que pode fazer sem ela. O programador apenas reproduz receita de bolo e não entende [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). E já vi alguns justificando que seria pela legibilidade, mas o nome da variável usada é completamente sem sentido, o que mostra que é mentira, por exemplo esse caso, artificial, eu sei, o nome quer dizer nada. Indicar que é uma saída? Dããã! Isso não torna o código mais legível.

Esse é um caso que, para todos os efeitos, apesar de funcionar, de dar o mesmo resultado sempre, do ponto de vista estilístico, e isto tem um pouco de gosto, considero o primeiro código um erro. Outro contexto em código próximo a este mas que faça sentido ter uma variável para documentar aí eu penso diferente.

A resposta do fernandosavio mostra que na implementação principal do Python é gerado um *bytecode* diferente se usar a variável, o que eu classificaria como lamentável já que ela não tem utilidade. Mas não me surpreende, Python não é uma linguagem adequada quando a preocupação é performance. Se precisa disso use outra linguagem.

Na verdade, poderia haver alguma otimização, e um dia possa vir a ser, então a resposta do hkotsubo que mostra que essa implementação realmente é mais lenta quando se usa a variável, mas é uma situação transitória.

Reforço que deve procurar a opção mais legível, se o uso da variável traz mais legibilidade deve usá-la prioritariamente, o que nem é o caso do exemplo da pergunta. Python é principalmente uma linguagem de *script*, por isso qualquer preocupação com micro otimização nela não faz sentido. O exemplo não deveria usar variável porque além de ser mais rápido é mais legível retornar logo um valor, uma variável que nada acrescenta é ruído.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as outras respostas, um jeito simples de comparar o desempenho é usar o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html).

```
import timeit

def exemplo_1(x):
    output = x + 1
    return output

def exemplo_2(x):
    return x + 1

n = 100000000
rep = 5
print(timeit.repeat("exemplo_1(1)", 'from __main__ import exemplo_1', number = n, repeat = rep))
print(timeit.repeat("exemplo_2(1)", 'from __main__ import exemplo_2', number = n, repeat = rep))
```

No exemplo acima estou chamando cada função 100 milhões de vezes (e repetindo cada ciclo de 100 milhões por 5 vezes). O retorno é uma lista com os tempos de cada um dos 5 ciclos:

```
[10.230189208560486, 10.76496154874702, 10.183613784861148, 9.914715879252743, 9.953630417515548]
[9.250180609985641, 9.20510965178623, 9.140656262847259, 9.346281658065251, 9.511226614071674]
```

O tempo pode variar a cada execução, pois depende de uma série de variáveis (como o seu hardware, se havia outros processos rodando na máquina, etc), então você não vai necessariamente ter os mesmos resultados que eu. Mas repare que a segunda versão (sem alocar a variável `output`) é ligeiramente mais rápida (cerca de 1 segundo de diferença, mais ou menos).

Mas isso foi para 100 milhões de execuções. Quando troquei o `n` para 1 milhão, a diferença entre a primeira e segunda versão caiu para cerca de **1 centésimo de segundo**. E para programas menores (em que a função será executada poucas vezes) fará menos diferença ainda, a ponto de ser irrelevante (para `n` igual 100, por exemplo, obtive diferenças na casa de 1 microssegundo - a sexta casa decimal das frações de segundo).

Sinceramente, a menos que seu código realmente precise rodar centenas de milhões de vezes seguidas e o desempenho seja extremamente crítico, você não deveria se preocupar com isso. A preocupação principal deveria ser a criação de código legível e o uso de variáveis onde isso fizer sentido, como já bem explicado na [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/351752/112052).

E se o seu sistema estiver apresentando problemas de desempenho, com certeza não será nestas funções. Neste caso, você deveria fazer testes específicos de desempenho para descobrir onde estão os gargalos.

Answer (score 3):

Tem sempre a função %time que eu uso no jupyter, mas neste caso a diferença tempo foi tão infimo que nao registrou a diferença: segue outro exemplo de conexão com uma API, que registrou o tempo.

[image: Seu codigo com %time]

[image: Segue outro exemplo de conexão com uma API, que registrou o tempo]

Estes comandos fazem parte do famoso magic commands do ipython. tem um bem interessante tambem em que apareceu uma diferença:

[image: Tem um bem interessante tambem em que apareceu uma diferença:]

Fora isto segue o link para voce ver todos os comandos magic:

[Ipython Magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Obs: desculpem se o post ta bagunçado sou novo por aqui, qualquer coisa edito!